# C# WPF MediaElement Volume only switches between 0 to 100 and ignores the rest of the slider

Tags: c#, wpf

I have binded the media element volume and the slider's value and for some reason the volume is either 0 or 100.
if the slider is all the way down(value = 0) its muting but if its anything else the volume is 100.

Media Element

```xml
<MediaElement x:Name="ME" Stretch="Fill"
              Volume="{Binding ElementName=VSlider,Path=Value,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MediaOpened="ME_MediaOpened"/>
```

Slider's code

```xml
<Slider x:Name="VSlider"
        Width="30" Height="{x:Static wsm:WindowSettings.wpHeight}" Maximum="100"
        Value="{Binding Source={x:Static wsm:WindowSettings.currentVolume }, Mode=OneWay}"
        TickFrequency="10" TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
        SmallChange="1" LargeChange="5" Orientation="Vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [MediaElement.Volume Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is defined as:

> The media's volume represented on a linear scale between 0 and 1. The default is 0.5.

Divide all the settings by 100.

```xml
<Slider x:Name="VSlider"
   Maximum="1" TickFrequency="0.1" SmallChange="0.01" LargeChange="0.05"
   ...
/>
```

Note: these Slider properties are all of type `double`.

You can use two properties per setting in the view model. One for display and user entry in a text box and the other for the slider value:

```cs
private double _volume; // Range [ 0.0 .. 1.0 ], bind to slider.
public double Volume
{
    get => _volume;
    set {
        if (value != _volume) {
            _volume = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Volume));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VolumeDisplay));
        }
    }
}

 // Range [ 0.0 .. 100.0 ], bind to text box.
public double VolumeDisplay
{
    get => 100.0 * _volume;
    set => Volume = value / 100.0;
}
```

See also: [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Thank you it worked.
 my actual goal is to create 4 textboxes for the volume as well.
One text box will be for "hundreds" "dozens" and so on while the last one is  the first number after zero.
Meaning if the user writes 1 at the first box the volume will be at max and the rest has to be 0.
and if the user wants to put 53.4 it will be 0 in the first box 5 in second 3 in third and 4 in last.

I tried to do that some time ago and something didn't work, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Create a view model that does the transformation from the internal values to the display values and vice versa. There will be at least two notifying (INotifyPropertyChanged) properties per setting having one common backing field..